# download attachment with mail listener

Tags: node.js, email, imap

I am using mail-listener4 to read mails and download attachments.
The mail fetching works perfectly, the problem is that when I try to download an attachment it's downloaded as an empty file (0 bytes).

Here is the code for the attachment download.
I am trying to download the first attachment as an initial proof of concept.

```
mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
// affichage des informations de mail
console.log("emailParsed", mail.attachments);
attachment=mail.attachments[0];
// console.log(attachment);
var file = fs.createWriteStream("./attachements/"+mailattachments[0].fileName);
  console.log(cpt)
  file.on('pipe',(file)=>{
    console.log("Test Download")
  })
  attachment.stream.pipe(file)
  });
```

When I try this way it's working perfectly:

```
mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment){
  console.log("Attachement")
  console.log(attachment.fileName)
  var file = fs.createWriteStream("./attachements/"+attachment.fileName);
  file.on('pipe',(file)=>{
      console.log('Test download ') 
      }); 
 attachment.stream.pipe(file)
  });`
```

I don't understand why one is working and the other is not. Can you please explain what's going on?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't simply go with the second approach?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JavaScript emailbut it would come as no surprise if the first part *is* empty.

Comment: yes @tripleee i wnat to filter the mails using the Subject and Sender  , with the 2nd approach i dont have any information about the sender or the subject

Comment: So what happens if you pick `[1]` or `[2]` instead of `[0]`?

Comment: :/ it's cause an exception , can't read property of undefined , [1] and [2] doesn't existe this array containts one element

Answer (score 0):

The attachment file is downloaded when "attachment" event is fired.

> Setting attachments: true will download attachments as buffer objects by default to the project directory.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener4

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: i know that the documentation says that but it's not working for me , even when i'm setting attachments to true, the events attachment is trigerred for each attachments but doesn't include the informations needed (Sender,Subject) to work with